# Select only the parent element in a dropdown list for a jquery hover function

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Sorry for the very vague title, I couldn't think of anything better. Basically, I am trying to make the parent element of my dropdown change a color when hovering over it, and remain that color when hovering over the children (the sub-menu). Here is a screenshot of the parent and children.

[image]

As you can see, when hovering over the parent the sub menu appears. The goal is to make it so when hovering over the sub menu, the 'services' remains orange. I have it working, but I am not happy with what I have come up with. I was wondering if someone has a better idea how to do this.

I used a jQuery hover function. Basically what it says is, when the sub menu of a particular menu item is hovered, then that particular menu item gets a class "main-menu-orange" (which is just a class that has color: #ff6b57).

It works, but I am not too happy with it because I have to select the individual item in the jQuery. I dont like this because if another menu item has children, I have to copy and paste the code and change the menu item ID. I don't want to keep having to copy and paste the hover function for every menu item that has children. Below is my code. By the way, I am using wordpress, and the classes such as menu-item and menu-item-has-children are automatically generated.

```
    jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-23 .sub-menu").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-23 a").addClass("main-menu-orange");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-23 a").removeClass("main-menu-orange");
        }
    );

    jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-26 .sub-menu").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-26 a").addClass("main-menu-orange");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-26 a").removeClass("main-menu-orange");
        }
    );
```

I also came up with the following code. This says if the sub-menu is hovered over, then the parents get the orange class.

```
     jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children a").addClass("main-menu-orange");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children a").removeClass("main-menu-orange");
        }
    );
```

This works, but the flaw is that all parents get the class. So when 'services' is hovered over, any parent on the nav turns orange. I have a couple elements on the nav that are parents.

Anyone have any ideas on how to clean this jQuery up? Maybe use 'this' or something.

Thanks!

Also, sorry about the mass amount of text, I tried to explain it  completely and thoroughly, unfortunately that came with a ton of text.

Comment: can you show us working fiddle or snippet mate

Answer (score 2):

you should use `$(this)` when you hover on `a` tag so it would only target the hovered `a` tag.

replace this lines of codes 
`jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-26 a").addClass("main-menu-orange");` 
`jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-23 a").addClass("main-menu-orange");` 
to 
`$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard Go to  Apperance->menu -> Show advanced menu properties

click checkbox of CSS Classes, it will so textbox for every menu then you can add Common class for parent menu.
and you can write css.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the solution by doing

```
jQuery("#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu").hover(
    function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().find("a").addClass("main-menu-orange");
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().find("a").removeClass("main-menu-orange");
    }
);
```